# How do I set the tags setting in vim to a dynamic value?

Tags: vim

In vim, you can set the `tags` setting (as opposed to a variable) via the `set` keyword in the `.vimrc` file or at runtime:

```
# .vimrc
set tags=tags

# runtime
:set tags=tags
```

What I would like to do is assume I always have my tags file at the root of my git repository:

```
# what I thought would 'just work' but did not..
set tags=system("git rev-parse --show-toplevel | xargs -I DIR echo 'DIR/tags'")
```

So that whenever I open a file inside a repo, the tags are referenced correctly.

---

How do I permanently and dynamically set tags like this?

Comment: Did you try using `BufRead` autocommand?

Comment: `:help 'tags'` has all the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to set it dynamically. You can search up the directory tree using a semi-colon `;` in the `tags` option as explained in section 2 of [`:help file-searching`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#file-searching).

The line

```vim
set tags=./tags;
```

should do what you want. You can also choose to limit upward search to the directory where all your projects reside:

```vim
set tags=./tags;/home/my_user/my_projects
```

Technically, this will overshoot by one directory but who cares?

If you are willing to use a plugin, [vim-gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags) will locate tags for you - and generate them for you (Disclaimer: I don't use that plugin myself). The plugin does contain a heuristic to locate a project's root directory based on markers like a `.git` dir, so this may be worth looking at even if you don't want to use it.